# How can you see what transaction isolation level an arbitrary oracle session is using

Tags: oracle, transactions, oracle10g, isolation-level

I am trying to find out what isolation level a particular session (not my own) has on an oracle server. Is there a v$.. view to get this?

Answer (score 8):

You can test bit 28 in the `flag` column in `v$transaction`[[1]](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=921464).

```
SELECT s.sid, s.serial#,
  CASE BITAND(t.flag, POWER(2, 28))
    WHEN 0 THEN 'READ COMMITTED'
    ELSE 'SERIALIZABLE'
  END AS isolation_level
FROM v$transaction t, v$session s
WHERE t.addr = s.taddr
  AND s.sid = :sid
  AND s.serial# = :serial;
```

Just remember that `v$transaction` only lists active transactions[[2]](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17110/dynviews_3114.htm); for example, you need to issue an insert/update/delete/merge, or use "for update"[[3]](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:3233191441609#19943265666689).