# How to check isoloation level?

Tags: database, performance, isolation-level

How do I check what IL is being set in my oracle DB. How do I change it? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: try this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663343/how-can-you-see-what-transaction-isolation-level-an-arbitrary-oracle-session-is

Comment: or this:  http://www.ehow.com/how_12227289_check-current-isolation-level-oracle.html

Answer (score 2):

To Set Isolation Level

> For **Read only Transaction** isolation level

Isolation Levels can be set as
For **Transaction level:**

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READONLY;
```

For **Session level:**

```
ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL READONLY;
```

> For **Serializable Transaction**  isolation level

**Transaction level:**

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
```

**Session level:**

```
ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
```

> For **Read Committed Transaction**  isolation level

**Transaction Level:**

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
```

**Session Level:**

```
ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
```

**To find the Isolation Level:**

When Transaction is in Progress:

```
SELECT s.sid, s.serial#,
   CASE BITAND(t.flag, POWER(2, 28))
      WHEN 0 THEN 'READ COMMITTED'
      ELSE 'SERIALIZABLE'
   END AS isolation_level
FROM v$transaction t 
JOIN v$session s ON t.addr = s.taddr AND s.sid = sys_context('USERENV', 'SID');
```

When the transaction is not in process

```
declare 
   trans_id Varchar2(100);
begin
   trans_id := dbms_transaction.local_transaction_id( TRUE );
end;
```